# How to run gunicorn inside python not as a command line?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask application.

I run it in production with this command:

```
python -m gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 "path.to.wsgi:return_app()"
```

Instead, I want to run it inside a my_file.py

I need a function to run and it should accept the app object and port binding and number of workers

How can I do that?

I need something like this **psudo code**:

```
import gunicorn

app = return_app()

gunicorn(workers=1, ip="0.0.0.0", port=5000, app=app)
```

the most important part to me is the `app=app` part

the main point is that I want to use the app object as an instance of Flask(). I want to directly give app object to gunicorn not throough addressing it in a string

**What I have tried:**
I have opened gunicorn library **main**.py file

```
from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
run()
```

to see how it works but could not figure it out

```
def run():
    """\
    The ``gunicorn`` command line runner for launching Gunicorn with
    generic WSGI applications.
    """
    from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import WSGIApplication
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
```

Answer (score 10):

Something like this works for me.
First I instantiate the BaseApplication class.
It has a `run()` method.
The details are on [how to create a custom application](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/custom.html) in gunicorn documentation.

```
if platform.uname().system.lower()=='linux':
    print("Detected Linux, Preparing gunicorn")        
    import gunicorn.app.base
    class StandaloneApplication(gunicorn.app.base.BaseApplication):

        def __init__(self, app, options=None):
            self.options = options or {}
            self.application = app
            super().__init__()

        def load_config(self):
            config = {key: value for key, value in self.options.items()
                    if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None}
            for key, value in config.items():
                self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

        def load(self):
            return self.application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Use a debugging session in port 5001    
    if platform.uname().system.lower()=='linux':
        print("Detected Linux, Running Gunicorn")
        options = {
            'bind': '%s:%s' % ('0.0.0.0', '5001'),
            'workers': number_of_workers(),
            # 'threads': number_of_workers(),
            'timeout': 120,
        }
        initialize()
        StandaloneApplication(app, options).run()
    else:
        print("Detected non Linux, Running in pure Flask")
        initialize()
        app.run(debug=True, host=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), port=5001)
```

Comment: Your MWE is not really complete. e.g. `number_of_workers()` `initialize()` and some others are missing. It would be lovely if you would complete it, so one can run it self contained.

Answer (score 8):

My goals weren't exactly the same: I was fine with specifying the app as a string (same as you do with gunicorn on the command line) rather than passing a python app object. Actually I'm not sure if passing a single app object really makes sense, because shouldn't gunicorn have a different app object in each worker that it spawns?

My main concern was that I run gunicorn without the help of `subprocess` or similar. I also used FastAPI rather than Flask, and (per the current recommended prod FastAPI setup) told gunicorn to spawn uvicorn workers.

This is what I ended up going with (in `myproject/web.py`):

```
import multiprocessing

from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import WSGIApplication


class StandaloneApplication(WSGIApplication):
    def __init__(self, app_uri, options=None):
        self.options = options or {}
        self.app_uri = app_uri
        super().__init__()

    def load_config(self):
        config = {
            key: value
            for key, value in self.options.items()
            if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None
        }
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)


def run():
    options = {
        "bind": "0.0.0.0:8000",
        "workers": (multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2) + 1,
        "worker_class": "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker",
    }
    StandaloneApplication("myproject.main:app", options).run()
```

My `StandaloneApplication` is very similar to (and is based on) the one in Zaero Divide's answer in this thread. However, I pass `app_uri`, and I inherit from `WsgiApplication` instead of from `BaseApplication`, which results in gunicorn starting up in basically the same way as when it's invoked from the command line.

Note: in `myproject/main.py`, I have `app = FastAPI()`. And in `pyproject.toml`, under `[tool.poetry.scripts]`, I have `web = "myproject.web:run"` - so I can start gunicorn with `poetry run web`. I'm also building an artifact with `shiv -c web myproject.whl -o web.pyz`, so I can then just run `/path/to/web.pyz` to start gunicorn.

Answer (score -4):

insert the following inside your my_file.py

```
from subprocess import run
run("gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 'path.to.wsgi:return_app()'".split(' '))
```

Comment: but  I need to give it the app directly as a python object, not as a string.

Comment: It still the same has limitations. My mindset is if I am running it inside python, I should be able to give the app directly to it. because gunicorn needs the app. and gunicorn is python libarray. I should be able to use it in python

Comment: run("gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 module_projet.wsgi".split(' '), cwd=path_to_wsgi)

Comment: @Amin Ba is it a django app or not?

Comment: look at the code I added